# What sort of parameters can be set using TR-069 (CWMP)?

Tags: networking, easycwmp

Some integrated Wifi Routers/Modems such as TD-W8901N offer TR-069 (CWMP), is it possible to manage parameters such ass SSIDs, DHCP, WAN mode using this feature? Is this protocol designed to work on devices installed behind ISP modems as well?

Comment: What is about reading the docs ? https://www.broadband-forum.org/technical/download/TR-069.pdf

Comment: I already read that document. According to it the answer would be yes. But I was expecting someone with hands-on experience to answer the question to talk about experiences with this type of device and ACS servers, like GenieAcs.  Just found another good sorce about real implementation of TR-069 http://www.axiros.com/tr-069/. Thank you Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on a number of factors - not least the data model objects supported by the client. Typical data models are TR-098 (typically not used for new implementations) and TR-181 (generic device data model, so  covers gateways and endpoints) for gateways, TR-104 for VoIP endpoints etc.

It gets more complicated, because a device likely will not support all the objects in a data model. Usually The ACS starts by reading the supported object from the device (their are other methods, but not well supported).

TR-069 is designed to work behind modems/routers, as its the device which connects to the ACS. As such most devices are hard-coded to communicate with their owners (usually the ISP). TR-069 for end user control of devices can generally be considered to be overkill - its complicated. As an operator, if you want to control 100k+ devices, then its definitely a good way to go

Answer (score 0):

you have to use STUN or XMPP that handle TR-069 clients behind NAT